# A queue with access to the last element

Tags: c#, queue

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257827/a-data-structure-like-queue-with-access-to-last-element#comment41191293_26257827) question, I realized there is no built-in data structure like that, so I implement my own queue using `List<T>`.

Please comment on performance (is there any better way instead of using `List<T>`?)

```
public class MyQueue<T>
{
    private List<T> _items;
    private int index;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _items.Count;
        }
    }

    public T Last
    {
        get
        {
            return _items[index];
        }
    }

    public MyQueue()
    {
        index = -1;
        _items = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
        index++;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        T i = _items[0];
        _items.RemoveAt(0);
        index--;
        return i;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return _items[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: [Deque (by Stephen Cleary)](http://nitodeque.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Seems to work, but is not optimal. You should use [Circual Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for a queue.

Comment: There are [LinkedList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ConcurrentCueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when trying to reimplement basic collections like this, you're going to have a lot of difficulty getting near the performance of the in-built .NET collections. As others have said, removing frequently from the beginning of a `List<T>` has very poor performance. However, just looking at the circular buffer article already linked, my immediate reaction is "yeesh, that is *not* complexity I'd want to add to my code!" Especially when I know somebody's already done it for me in the existing `Queue<T>`!

So in situations like this, the answer is usually to either be willing to sacrifice performance, or to try to make use of the actual collection as much as possible. In fact, all you want is a queue that has a little extra functionality, so why not do just that, using composition? There's no `IQueue<T>` interface in .NET, so we can't implement the decorator pattern, but we can get close:

```
class MyQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _inner = new Queue<T>();

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _inner.Count;
        }
    }

    public T Last { get; private set; }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _inner.Enqueue(item);
        Last = item;
    }
    //...
}
```

---

In more general review terms, the code you wrote looks good. A few minor points:

- `index` and `_items` follow different naming schemes.
- `MyQueue` is not a good class name. Try to pick a name that actually describes the class
- As firda said, you shouldn't try to keep track of the index yourself, it's just `Count - 1`. You're tracking the same thing in two different ways.
- You may want to consider implementing `IEnumerable<T>`. Using iterator methods, this wouldn't be too complicated, and it'd allow the full power of LINQ to be used with your class. However, I would definitely file this under YAGNI until it actually comes up as something you find yourself wanting, unless your intention with this code is to put it in a public library for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

**First to note, your code seems to work and the code-style is OK.

There is not much to review :) ...but still:**

Using the `List<T>` not to write reallocation (growing) yourself is fine, but the `index` is unnecessary, as `index = Count - 1` all the time, it is redundant. `Last` will throw [IndexOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the queue is empty. It would be better to check and throw [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
public T Last
{
    get
    {
        if(Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");
        return _items[Count - 1];
    }
}
```

The main (time complexity) problem is in `Dequeue`:

```
public T Dequeue()
{
    T i = _items[0];
    _items.RemoveAt(0);  //<<<< this Remove
    index--;
    return i;
}
```

Which you should try to avoid (if you plan to have good Queue) by using [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Use two indexes - one for writing, one for reading and reset them to zero when they reach `_items.Count` which becomes your `Capacity`. Leave one slot empty to never have write_index == read_index for both empty and full queue. You could even enhance it to create [Doubly-Ended Queue](http://nitodeque.codeplex.com/) that you can add/remove to/from both ends.